# Как лучше всего сверстать

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Долго думаю, как правильней всего подойти к этому вопросу. Хотя вроде ничего сложного и, разумеется, у меня есть идеи. Однако я уверен, что подобное - стандартная проблема в верстке. И для ее решения придумано какое-то гениальное и просто решение.
[image: Текст слева, изображение слева]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю такой вариант, где левый и правый блок в планшетной версии встанут друг над  другом и где фон уже будет не от родителя т.е не `inherit` а скажем в `rgba` в действительности надо будет скопировать код и сохранить их в файлы со своим расширением и проверить - я тестил на 768px, к сожалению фон из тырнета не отображается:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #131515;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.elem {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.elem1 {
  background: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.elem1 h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.elem1 p {
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.elem1 a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.elem2 {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(https://get.pxhere.com/photo/desk-computer-writing-screen-apple-keyboard-technology-mouse-workspace-office-brand-design-document-916386.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

p.size {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

@media (max-width:812px) {
  .element,
  .elem1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .elem1 {
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
  }
  .elem2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<div class="element">
  <div class="elem elem1">
    <p>
      <span>jun, 2010</span>
      <span>|</span>
      <span>in <a href="#">Culture</a></span>
    </p>
    <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione placeat fuga quod quae unde, itaque soluta, dolorum modi. Voluptas, saepe.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, dolorum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, voluptatem. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="elem elem2"></div>
</div>
```